# How to make a dynamic range in worksheet SelectionChange procedure in VBA event driven programming?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to design a question paper template in excel, every question has four different types of answer like

```
"Yes/No", 
"Ture/False", 
"Multiple Choice/Single Answer",
"Multiple Choice/Multiple Answer".
```

if user select `"Yes/No"` and try to answer more then two answers then it pop up an error message.
if user select "`Multiple Choice/Multiple Answer"` and select only one answer and move to another cell or column it popup error message. 
...and so on for other types of questions.

I have use event-driven programming for this, use worksheet SelectionChange procedure. my code is working fine but it is not dynamic it is just working for only one question while I have 100 questions in my template.

four columns are used in this template
`Column A, B, C and D` name respectively `"Sr.No."` Question no. is mention, "`Question`" Question is in this column, `"Answer Type"` Answer type is mention here in the drop-down list., "Correct Option" user need to be select True from here for the right option.

My code is here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' section 1

' for Multiple Choice/Multiple answer
' if user select less than 2 answer
rw = 9
rng1 = rw + 1
rng2 = rw + 4

If Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Mutilple Choice/ Mutiple Answer" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") < 2 Then
    MsgBox "Select at least 2 ""TRUE"" option"

' for Multiple Choice/Single Answer
' if user select more than 1 answer
ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Mutilple Choice/Single Answer" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Select only 1 ""TRUE"" option"

    ' if user doesn't select any answer
    ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Mutilple Choice/Single Answer" And _
        WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Select only 1 ""TRUE"" option"

' for Yes/No Answer
' if user select more than 1 answer
ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Yes/No" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Select only 1 ""TRUE"" option"

        ' if user doesn't select any answer
        ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Yes/No" And _
            WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Select at least 1 ""TRUE"" option"

' for True/False Answer
' if user select more than 1 answer
ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "True/False" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Select only 1 ""TRUE"" option"

        ' if user doesn't select any answer
        ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "True/False" And _
            WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Select at least 1 ""TRUE"" option"


' for Free Form(Essay) answer
ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Free Form(Essay)" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & rng1 & ":" & "D" & rng2), "TRUE") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Do not select any option,it is a free form question"

'ElseIf Worksheets("Question paper").Range("C" & rw).Value = "Free Form(Essay)" And _
'    Worksheets("Main Sheet").Range("C32") = "" Then
'    MsgBox "Please fill details in cell C32 in ""Main Sheet"" tab"

End If
End Sub
```

In my current code, It is just working for one question, to implement it for another 99 questions, I have to copy paste same code 99 times with assign a variable for question row number.

I expect a dynamic code for 100 or more question.

Answer (score 1):

Tested it it works find if you use the Target.row value for your current row

```
rw = Target.row
```

because you only use a fixed value of 9 and not the current target row to check

Comment: Thanks for your answer DeBugOfen, but if you see my code closely error message will pop up until user select the right no. of an answer. so if I put this code rw = Target.row. when a user jumps another cell it will change rw value and code will give an error in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

first I put this formula in another column =IF(AND(B10<>"",C10<>""),"Q",0) this formula give me the question number is which question user is working.
In column "B" user need to enter a question and in column "C" there is a drop down for question type like "Yes/No", "Ture/False"...
in column "D" I get the "Q" at the front of a question in which user is working. at the end of column "D", I put =sum formula so I got the question number.

in another 2 columns I make a table where I mention row number against each question like this:
Q No.  Row No.
1        10
2        15
3        25

now simply by using vlookup formula got the row number of question in which user is working.

now I simply assign this cell value in a variable in my VBA code like this:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

```
rw = Range("XFB762").Value
rng1 = rw + 1
rng2 = rw + 4

If Worksheets("Question paper").Range("D" & rw).Value = "Multiple Choice/ Multiple Answer" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E" & rng1 & ":" & "E" & rng2), "TRUE") < 2 Then
    MsgBox "Select at least 2 ""TRUE"" option"
```

Now the range is dynamic . and it is working fantastic.